# Show workflow while running

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am trying out Workflow Foundation 4.  Is it possible to show the workflow while it is running, with some sort of indicator of state (e.g. green box around activity = running)?  The workflow would have to be read-only.  However, I would also like to right click an activity and bring up info like how long the activity took to run, current logging state, etc.

**Edit:** I found the following links, but they are not for Workflow Foundation **4**.  Does anyone know what it has been replaced with?

WorkflowView: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617016.aspx

Workflow Monitor Sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741706.aspx